# Как правильно расставить знаки препинания в предложении?1

Tags: синтаксис

Вопрос об ответственности лица, осуществляющего хотя и формально с правоохранительной целью, но все же объективную деятельность.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос об ответственности лица, осуществляющего, хотя и формально, с правоохранительной целью, но все же объективную деятельность.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос об ответственности лица, осуществляющего, хотя и формально с правоохранительной целью, но всё же объективную, деятельность.